# getString() from within java code

Tags: android, string

I'm trying to acces my strings.xml from within the java code, but for some reason I can only acces some default android strings.
This is what I do:

```
private static Context context;
context = getApplicationContext();

context.getString(R.string.somthing);
```

The R.string contains some strings but not what I have in strings.xml.

Comment: You are probably inporting the  wrong 'R' class. Import the generated 'R' class located in /gen/ and not the 'android.R' class.

Comment: by the soud of it akalucas is right. This is a common mistake made by rookie android coders (including myself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you import android.R or your generated R file ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you imported `android.R` so just remove it and import your `R.class` like as

```
import your.package.name.R;
```

here `your.package.name` is your package name which you write in your `Manifest.xml` file.

Comment: if some one answered the same already that you are about to answer. prefer voting up rather posting same.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code instead

```
Resources resources = context.getResources();
resources.getString(R.string.something)
```